# Powershell how to get a list of running processes and run them through the MD5 algorithm

Tags: windows, powershell, process, md5, list

Hi i need to be able to get a list of every process running on my windows 10 and run them through the MD5 algorithm. Is there a way to do this automatically in powershell?

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: This question doesnt make much sense as it is.  What ***exactly*** are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi sorry i'll try to make it clearer. I am trying to find a process running on my computer that matches an MD5 hash that i already know. I was hoping i would be able to automate this using powershell but unfortunately using google hasn't turned anything up.  I want to grab the list of processes currently running on my computer and process them (not sure if correct term sorry) through the md5 algorithm and see if i can find one that matches the md5 hash i already know.

Comment: What are you trying to get the MD5 hash of? The process names, or the contents of the `.exe` files that are running?

Comment: I'm curious why you want the hash of the process name instead of just using the process name. What advatage does comparing the hash get yoou for a string that is as short as process names are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt as easy as it should be.  PowerShell can MD5 hash a *file* natively (using `Get-FileHash`), but not a string.

Fortunately, MS provides a solution [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-StringHash-aa843f71).

```
#http://jongurgul.com/blog/get-stringhash-get-filehash/ 
Function Get-StringHash([String] $String,$HashName = "MD5") 
{ 
$StringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 
[System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create($HashName).ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($String))|%{ 
[Void]$StringBuilder.Append($_.ToString("x2")) 
} 
$StringBuilder.ToString() 
}
```

Copy that function and paste it into a PowerShell prompt.  That function called `Get-StringHash` will be saved for that PowerShell session.

Test MD5 hashing the word "test" by typing:

> Get-StringHash "test" "MD5"

And you should get the MD5 hash below:

> 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6

Once that is done, you can use that function, along with `Get-Process` to get the process names and MD5 of the names as seen below:

```
get-process | ForEach-Object {write-host $_.Name ; Get-Stringhash "$_.Name" "MD5"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is a utility from Microsoft named Sysmon which is typically intended for collecting low level system information for the purpose of malware tracking. It is installed as a service and can be configured to record the file hash of each process that is launched in the event log. You can configure which hash types (md5,sha1,sha2,etc) to record through a config file. If this would help accomplish your goal, you can read more about it [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/motiba/2016/10/18/sysinternals-sysmon-unleashed/).

[image: eventlog]